# Typessing on a grid (Quantum spaces by Jean-Luc Doumont) support in latex

Tags: typography, layout, grid-typesetting

I saw the [presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkBCeOBbAmM) of Jean-Luc Doumont on typesetting on a grid.
He talks about some macros in this presentation, but I wonder if there is any package in latex yet, to support this.

Here are the [sample pages](https://www.principiae.be/pdfs/TM&Th-samplepages.pdf) of this book.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I am using the tufte class very often, however it has nothing in common with a grid-like layout.

Comment: I would dare to say there is none, maybe one among LaTeX3 packages (galleys or something like that). There are also options in ConTeXt, maybe more advanced.

Comment: TeX is known for not great at grid-typesetting. Jean-luc Doumont’s book utilizes TeX macros (not LaTeX codes) to have more control over the layout. In his book, everything was set in a very “controlled” environment (he talked about deliberately writing paragraphs in perfect rectangles in the video). In short, if you are looking for grid-solution in a “high-level” and “automatic” way, you probably have to switch to ConTeXt (still not perfect when it comes to complicated displayed multi-line maths). But, you can always go for complete manual (like the good old days of hot metal).

Comment: Just wondering, did any body tried to mimic this with tabulars? Yes, there is no text flow between pages but that is probably neither the case for the custom TeX system he uses. I bet every page is crafted individually.

Comment: The closest match to a grid layout, like you may know from FrameMaker or Scribus, is using package flowfram. It offers 3 types of frames: flow for the running Latex text, static and dynamic (e.g. to move „chapter names“ around your page). Once you know the layout distribution by pagenumber, you can switch on and off predefined frames, to mimick variable page layout. // It seems to work, but can be some kind of fragil for a flowfram beginner like me. However, you feel the mathematical background with female touch of flowframs author :)

Comment: An alternative can be using newenvironments. E.g. the figures may work fine using \marginpar (need to verify this). Or use tikz nodes to move entities around. // There are certainly more option, as after all, at the low level all Latex became Tex-ish, after some expansions.

Comment: As I imagined, each *paragraph* is written exactly as a rectangle in most pages of his book https://youtu.be/vkBCeOBbAmM?t=1694.

Comment: @MS-SPO, I didn't know about flowfram. I remember when I saw Aldus PageMaker (4.0?) for Windows 3.1 for the first time and it had floating boxes in which the text could flow from one to the other, even in different pages. It blew my mind.

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt , I didn't try to use it to replicate the grid approach, but isn't the package `textpos` supposed to do something like this. It even starts by defining a rectangular grid. I guess one has to handle the gaps manually and all that, but it is a good first step.

Comment: There is always more than one way to do it … Flowfram supports layout variations with Latex you need e.g. for brochures or posters or not too complicated special book layouts. Recreating any printed magazine will make you want to leave Latex and running with Scribus or Publisher for example. Have a closer analytical look at any magazine next time. You’ll recognize a handful of predefined layouts, modified at the speed of a few mouse clicks … i.e. being hard to systemize. Different workflow, different requirement.

Comment: In the past 3 years, I tried different approaches, but none was satisfying. I think LaTeX is the wrong tool and that TeX is better suited. However, I never had the time to learn plain TeX.